# Android studio: cant recieve push messages on sdk < 26 when app is on foreground

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, android-notifications

I want to make my app revieve push-notifications on a foreground. It works ok on my emulator (recieving on a foreground and background), but app crushes when push comes to my phone on foreground.
Here is my code:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESC);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more)
                    .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                    .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            manager.notify(1, builder.build());
        }
```

My phone has android 7.1 version so app crushes on line with NotificationChannels. As i understood, NotificationChannels not availiable for that old versions of android. I want to find a way, how to rewrite NotificationCompat.Builder for sdk versions < 25. If i try to do write it in old style, Android Studio says that methid is depricated.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
```

What a correct way to make NotificationCompat.Builder work on old sdk versions? Or how can i make my app recieve messages on a foreground with android versions that not supporting NotificationChannels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)` for any SDK level but you need to create `NotificationChannel` for devices with SDK >= 26 and there is no need to create `NotificationChannel` if the SDK < 26.

---

Try this code

```
private void createNotification() {

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // only create notification channel if SDK >= 26
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESC);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());


    manager.notify(1, builder.build());

}
```